# sed - capture a group and replace only one character

Tags: regex, sed, replace, capture

I have the following question, a file with pattern like this:

```
1XYZ00
```

so the result would be

```
2XYZ00
```

I want to change only the first number with another number, for example 9 and not changing anything for the rest of the patern.

I really need to capture this pattern **1XYZ00** and only this one and replace the first number with another one.
I this file I can have numbers but with different pattern and those must not be modified.

The OS is CentOS 7.

Here is what I have tested

```
sed -E 's/1{1}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}/9{1}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}/g' ~/input.txt > ~/output.txt
```

I also tried with capture group:

```
sed --debug -E -r 's/1\(1{1}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}\)/9\1/g' ~/input.txt > ~/output.txt
```

The sed's debug mode tells me that the pattern matches but no replacement is made.

I think I am pretty close, does any expert could help me please ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: can you add some more examples? does `sed 's/[0-9]/2/' ~/input.txt` solve your problem?

Comment: thanks Sundeep,
Nope it replaces every  2 with another number, but if I Have an IP like 127.0.0.1 it will also replace, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat ip.txt
foo 1XYZ00
xyz 1 2 3
hi 3XYZ00
1XYZ0A
cool 3ABC23

$ # matches any number followed by 3 uppercase and 2 digit characters
$ sed -E 's/[0-9]([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2})/9\1/' ip.txt
foo 9XYZ00
xyz 1 2 3
hi 9XYZ00
1XYZ0A
cool 9ABC23

$ # matches digit '1' followed by 3 uppercase and 2 digit characters
$ sed -E 's/1([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2})/9\1/' ip.txt
foo 9XYZ00
xyz 1 2 3
hi 3XYZ00
1XYZ0A
cool 3ABC23
```

---

Issue with OP's attempts:

- `1{1}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}` is same as `1[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}`
- Using `9{1}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}` in replacement section will give you those characters literally. They don't have any special meaning.
- `s/1\(1{1}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}\)/9\1/` this one does use capture groups but `()` shouldn't be escaped with `-E` option active and `1{1}` shouldn't be part of the capture group

Comment: Thanks a lot Sundeep !!
I have tested `code sed -E 's/[0-9]([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2})/2\1/' ip.txt` and it works like a charm, this is exactly what I want ! 

Thanks a lot also for the explanations, I mark this thread as solved ! 
I was so closed ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is enough for you.

```
sed -i 's/1/9/' input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Henry, but I don't think it will fit my needs, Sorry I forgot to mention that in the file I also have other several numbers, that I don't want to matche/replace.
So I need to capture the pattern and replace only the first position, with something else.

Comment: You're welcome! I also think you're very close to answer.